# Using a prompt to set options

Tags: options, dialog-window, counting

I am creating a toolbar.  One of the buttons on my toolbar is this setcounter button below.

```
setcounter = Dynamic[Button["Set Counters", {


    SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
     CounterAssignments -> {{"StaticChapter", 3}, {"StaticSection", 
        5}}]},

   Appearance -> "Palette"]]
```

As shown, this button sets each counter to 3 and 5 respectively.  I would like to create a prompt in the form of a popup window or dialog that will allow the user to enter their own positive integers. And then the option be set based upon those numbers.

I know I probably just need one line of code before "SetOptions..." but I can't seem to get anything to work.  I've tried dialogs... but I can't get it to wait for the inputs before setting the option.  Any Ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
DynamicModule[{counters, oldcounters},

 Button["Set Counters",
  oldcounters = 
   CurrentValue[InputNotebook[], {CounterAssignments}][[All, 2]];

  counters = DialogInput[{x = 0, y = 0},
    Column[{
      "SetCounters:",
      Row[{"StaticChapter ", InputField[Dynamic[x,(x = Round[#]) &], Number]}],
      Row[{"StaticSection ", InputField[Dynamic[y,(y = Round[#]) &], Number]}], 
      Row[{CancelButton[DialogReturn[$Canceled]], 
        Button["Reset", DialogReturn[{x, y}], ImageSize -> Automatic]}]
      }]
    ];
  If[counters =!= $Failed && counters =!= $Canceled, 
   SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
    CounterAssignments -> {{"StaticChapter", 
       counters[[1]]}, {"StaticSection", counters[[2]]}}],

   SetOptions[InputNotebook[], 
    CounterAssignments -> {{"StaticChapter", 
       oldcounters[[1]]}, {"StaticSection", oldcounters[[2]]}}]
   ], Appearance -> "Palette", Method -> "Queued"]
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you Mike.  This works great!  I was thinking their would be a simpler solution but based upon what you've done maybe not?

Comment: Spoke to soon.... Something isn't working with your code. If I try calling one of the counterboxs it doesn't work.  I'm thinking it might be because your counters are stored as string and not numbers?

Comment: Yep!  Change both occurrences of String to Number in your code and it works perfect!  Thank you!

Comment: @MichaelMcCain yes correct. Also you need integers so I added a bit more to ensure that.